# Easier way to do this? - CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I've made a simple menu, where the hover effect is moving with the cursor, but it feels like there should be a way to automate the process more. Right now, im saying how big and where the hover effect should be, based on how much text there is in the menu by manually putting pixels into the width, and left margin.

HTML

```
<div class="sticky">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" >
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <a class="th logoconfig" href="#">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/220x60&text=[Logo]" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="one"><a href="#">Forside</a></li>
      <li class="two"><a href="#">Bartender</a></li>
      <li class="three"><a href="#">Deejay</a></li>
      <li class="four"><a href="#">Pakkeløsninger</a></li>
      <li class="five"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.top-bar {
  background-color: #3e6979;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  background-color: #265364;
  height: 5rem;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  width: 6.3rem;
}

.activelinkone {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  width: 6.3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease;
}

.activelinktwo {
  margin-left: 17.2%;
  width: 8rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease;
}

.activelinkthree {
  margin-left: 38.5%;
  width: 5.5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease;
}

.activelinkfour {
  margin-left: 53.5%;
  width: 11.5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease;
}

.activelinkfive {
  margin-left: 81.7%;
  width: 8rem;
  transition: all 0.2s 0.1s ease;
}

.one:hover ~ .box {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 6.3rem;
}

.two:hover ~ .box {
  margin-left: 17.2%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 8rem;
}

.three:hover ~ .box {
  margin-left: 38.5%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 5.5rem;
}

.four:hover ~ .box {
  margin-left: 53.5%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 11.5rem;
}

.five:hover ~ .box {
  margin-left: 81.7%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  width: 8rem;
}

.top-bar-section ul {
  margin-right: 5.5rem;
}

.top-bar-section ul li {
  background: none;
}

.top-bar-section ul li > a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

.top-bar-section ul li:not(.has-form) > a {
  background: none;
}

.top-bar-section ul li:hover:not(.has-form) > a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.16rem;
  background: none;
}

.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
  background: none;
}

.activelink {
  background-color: #3e6979;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.stick {
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 0rem;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0rem;
}

.logoconfig {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.logoconfigsmall {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.logoconfigsmall img {
  height: 58px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('.logoconfig').addClass("logoconfigsmall");
    } else {
        $('.logoconfig').removeClass("logoconfigsmall");
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('.toppen').removeClass("topdesign");
    } else {
        $('.toppen').addClass("topdesign");
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('.top-bar').addClass("stick");
    } else {
        $('.top-bar').removeClass("stick");
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('.box').css({
            "height": "3.73rem"
        });

    } else {
        $('.box').css({
            "height": "5rem"
        });

    }

});


function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

var page = getUrlParameter('page');


if (page == "nav1") {
    $('.box').addClass("activelinkone");
}

if (page == "nav2") {
    $('.box').addClass("activelinktwo");
}

if (page == "nav3") {
    $('.box').addClass("activelinkthree");
}

if (page == "nav4") {
    $('.box').addClass("activelinkfour");
}

if (page == "nav5") {
    $('.box').addClass("activelinkfive");
}
```

**Example:** 
[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYaoQj)

If I add another `a` tag to the menu, it gets completely messed up. It seems like a lot of work for such a simple menu.

Comment: you could make all your menu options the same width; might need to re-label the long one.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, about html structure: an `<ul>` accepts only `<li>` elements as children, you can't add a `<div>` element to it, because its an error and every browser will try to calculate distances and fix it in its way. So you have to put it outside, after the list.

then, about `.box` animation: you can't use a css static percentual measure to calculate its position, you can calculate `.box` position using the relative `<a>` element `offsetLeft` javascript property